# How to integrate spring data elastic search with DDD principles?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, domain-driven-design, spring-data-elasticsearch

**Problem:**

Suppose the domain contains 3 aggregates and a search operation given a query string is executed towards a web application. The query string must be used to search all of the fields in each aggregate and return 3 sets of each aggregate to the user as the resulting query. The web application has two data stores: RDBMS and Elastic Search. How do we integrate the RDBMS+ES infrastructure to the domain layer?

**Proposed Solution:**

The best way I can think of is to maintain the persistence ignorance of the domain layer by hiding the RDBMS+ES infrastructure implementation behind each domain repository. Here is my proposed solution in pseudo-code format:

```
AggregateRepository
- jpaAggregateRepository
- elasticAggregateRepository

@Transactional
+ save(Aggregate) {
 Denormalize Aggregate to AggregateDocument (because one aggregate can span many tables)
 Persist Aggregate to jpaAggregateRepository
 Persist AggregateDocument to elasticAggregateRepository
}

+ find() {
 Extract PKs from elasticAggregateRepository.find()
 return jpaAggregateRepository(PKs)
}
```

By doing so, I have successfully prevented any infrastructure logic to pollute my domain layer. To finally achieve the use case, I can execute the following in my application layer:

```
aggregateOneRepository.find(term)
aggregateTwoRepository.find(term)
aggregateThreeRepository.find(term)
```

and probably combine the 3 sets of aggregates into a DTO to be consumed by the client.

Is this solution dirty? If so, please do suggest a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're on the right track persistence ignorance wise. However, leveraging the RDBMS + ElasticSearch for a simple Search operation when you could only query ES is kind of a waste of resources.

A [CQRS](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) approach would allow you to distinguish between cases when you need to initiate a transaction against the SQL database in order to write stuff (commands) and when you only read ElasticSearch (queries).

Comment: What did you mean by this phrase "when you could only query ES is kind of a waste of resources"?

Comment: RDBMSs are good at keeping your data consistent under a lot of concurrency for writes. Elastic Search is good at finding and reading stuff very fast, but writing to it is rarely your primary goal. In other words, the good old OLTP vs OLAP distinction. Use the right tool for the right situation, not both tools every time ;)

Comment: Do you mean CQRS would make a better and cleaner solution for my use case? All I wanted to do is to use elastic search for search operations but all the data should still be retrieved from the database since data normalization is one of the strengths of RDBMS.

Comment: All I mean is that you could remove that `jpaAggregateRepository(PKs)` line from `find()` if you took what comes out of Elastic Search and turned it directly into objects.

Comment: Ohh. As a matter of fact, I don't have to worry about the data consistency of the ES data store thanks to the aggregate concept of DDD, don't I?

Comment: Not really... it's more that `find(searchTerms)` is a read operation. Usually, you're going to display the result to the user in some shape or form, not modify the data. So why involve the RDBMS in that operation when you could just ask Elastic Search?

Comment: The consistency of the ES store is guaranteed by what you put in the `save()` method. You don't want to touch that (although there could be more elegant ways of doing it).

Comment: Following the train of your thoughts, are we still under the assumption that the queried object through ES is the same aggregate entity used in saving?

Comment: No it isn't, that's exactly the point of CQRS :) The write model is different from the read model. And they are also returned by different "repositories". Two separate data stores, two separate object models.

Comment: Ohh, now I'm starting to understand your point. Haha. What about the save method? What do you propose for a more elegant way of saving?

Comment: Elastic search saving would probably be decoupled from RDBMS saving, maybe with domain events in between - although that's an entirely separate subject.

Comment: To be clear, saving to ES is a different responsibility from saving to the DB. You need two separate objects to do that. The application service could call the two of them in a sequence. Another option could be to consider ES indexing as a mere side effect and do it by listening to what happens in the domain instead of including it as a full fledged step of the main process. Although it can be done in-process at first, this paves the way for asynchronous updates of ES, *if you need it* later.

Comment: Suppose the ES save operation is done by listening on DB save operation, is it possible to encapsulate the two operations in a transaction? Case in point, if ES save operation fails, DB save operation must rollback.

Comment: If it is done in-process, yes, you can wrap it all in a transaction. Otherwise you'll often have a middle man responsible for delivering messages and it will redeliver them to one of the subscribers if it fails. But for now it is perfectly fine if you just call the two saves in a sequence in a transaction. My initial point was just for the object that persists in DB and the one that indexes in ES to be separate.